# Post data from MVC controller to view using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which consist of a dropdown and some labels.
Based on the selection of the value from the dropdown the relevant data needs to be populated on the labels.

I have used ajax jquery for posting to the server based on dropdown selection but not able to fetch data as my httppost action method is already returning proper data but it is not caught in view.

Dropdown javascript code

```
   $(function () {

       $("#Year").change(function () {
           var Year = $('#Year').val();
           // var str = $(this).val();
           if (Year != "" || Year != "--Select--") {
               //alert("hi");
               $.ajax({

                   type: "POST",
                   url: '@Url.Action("Index", "TeamProbReview")',
                    data: { empcode: Year },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(msg){ } }); 

                //function successFunc(data, status) { $('#txtTradeQty').val(data); } //alert("success" + data + $('#txtTradeQty').val()); 
                //function errorFunc() { alert('error'); } successFunc,  alert(data); 
            }
            else { alert("Pls Select a Employee"); }

       }); 
   });//end of doc ready

</script>
```

Controller code

```
 public ActionResult Index(string empcode)
         {
            DropdownValue();
            data.spx_Probation_display_mvc(empcode);
            //TeamProbReviewModel tmProbRe = new TeamProbReviewModel();
            var emp = data.spx_Probation_display();


        var tmProbRe1 = (from e in emp
                                   select new TeamProbReviewModel
                                   {

                                       emp_name = e.emp_name,
                                       Ecode = e.emp_no,
                                       Department = e.Department
                                       //Role = e.FunctionalRole,
                                       //AttendanceLocation = e.attnlocation,
                                       //DateofJoining = e.JOINDATE,
                                       //ExpectedDOC = e.expected_doc,

                                       //ProbationPeriod = e.Probation_Period


                                   }).FirstOrDefault();
        //List<TeamProbReviewModel> ls = new List<TeamProbReviewModel>(EmpItems.ToList());
        //var emplist = (IEnumerable<TeamProbReviewModel>)ls;
        //ViewData["Person"] = new SelectList(iPersonList, "Id", "Name");

        //List<Student1> ls = data.spx_students(2, "vikas").ToList<Student1>();




        return View(tmProbRe1);

    }
```

Comment: $.ajax({
 
                       type: "POST",
                       url: '@Url.Action("Index", "TeamProbReview")',
                        data: { empcode: Year },
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#Year').val();
                        }

Comment: sorry nobody will give u easy built code here,
you need to show your efforts

Comment: And now, what's the problem here? everything looking fine

Comment: code is calling the post method but it is not populating the data on the view as in the actionmethod i am creating a object of the model class and storing the values in it and returning it in the view.

Comment: did you tried debugging the value of "data" in ajax success, are they in correct format?

Comment: @user3789804 plese edit your question and update the code there so that it'll get more attention and help. Your question is likely to be closed otherwise (*not everybody reads comments*)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <select id="Year">
    <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<span id="lblSpan"></span>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Year").change(function () {
                var Year = $(this).val();
                if (Year != "Select") {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/TeamProbReview/Index',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { empcode: Year },
                     success: function (msg) {//tmProbRe1 result catch in msg and show in labal
                            if (msg != null) {
                                $("#lblSpan").text(msg);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please select emp code");
                }
            });
        });
     [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(string empcode)
            {
                  var tmProbRe1 = (from e in emp
                             where e.empcode==empcode
                             select new TeamProbReviewModel
                          {     emp_name = e.emp_name,
                                 Ecode = e.emp_no,
                                 Department = e.Department
                             }).FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(tmProbRe1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
retun result in json
```

Comment: var obj1 = JSON.parse(msg);$("#lblSpan").text(obj1); change code of line in jquery

Comment: I have a view which consist of a dropdown and some labels for e.g @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Ecode and based on the selection from the dropdown using ajax i am posting the control to HTTPpost method of the action method and returning the data in the model class object but unable to retrieve it on the view.Is it a issue of the ajax????

Comment: you have to use json for it @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem,new{id="lblSpan"}) and bind id with json value in success function

Comment: can you show me an example for  binding id with json value in success function.

Comment: already done in example success:function(msg){$("lblSpan").val(msg);} or give me the result which come in msg

Comment: result is actually a class object which contains the values.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it, you want only make AJAX request and see how values are magically binded to view. It doesn't work like that. You should process your AJAX results in `success` function (refer [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
        if (data && data.label1)
            $('label1').text(data.label1);
    }
});
```

So, if you want magic data-binding, learn some MVVM concepts and examine proper libs like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)

**UPD:**

To work with JSON in ASP.NET you need a package like `Newtonsoft.Json`. It will help you to serialize model object in controller and then populate it in view. There're a lot of examples of usage, like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78928/Create-JSON-from-C-using-JSON-Library. Google bless you

Comment: I want to fetch values from the model class object which i am returning in the controller after the dropdown post to the server using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $("#Year").change(function () {
           var Year = $(this).val();
           if (Year != "Select") {
               $.ajax({
                   url: '/TeamProbReview/Index',
                   type: 'post',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: { empcode: Year },
                   success: function (result) {
                       $("#Ecode").val(result.Ecode);
                       $("#EmpName").val(result.emp_name);
                       $("#Department").val(result.Department);
                       $("#Role").val(result.Role);
                       $("#AttendanceLocation").val(result.AttendanceLocation);
                       //$("#DateofJoining").val(result.DateofJoining);
                       $("#ProbationPeriod").val(result.ProbationPeriod);
                    }
                });
           }
           else {
               alert("Please select emp code");
           }
       });
   });//end of doc ready
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $("#drpop").change(function () {
     var code = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({ 
    url: '/Ordering/OrderingTable',
    type: 'post',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: { OperCode: code },
     success:function(msg){
alert(msg);
     } }); }); 
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult OrderingTable(string OperCode) 
    {
     Orderingbll order = new Orderingbll(); 
    var result = order.ListCategory(OperCode);//here you write your code
     return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```